# Using string as a variable in object destructuring in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm mapping over an array of objects in React, and I'm using object destructuring ({}) to render values into div, like so:

```js
{array?.map((item) => (
  <div key={item.ID}>
    <p>{item.EN}</p>
```

It works, but I would like to replace the value within curly brackets with a variable, and have it evaluated as a variable. This is what I want to achieve:

Example object values:

```js
const object = {"DE": "Deutsch", "EN": "English"}
const language = "DE"
// ...
<p>{item.{language}}</p>
```

I want it to return "Deutsch", and not "item.DE".

I tried all possible variations with brackets and $ sign, but it keeps returning the value as "item.DE" instead of evaluating the passed string as an object field.

Comment: `{item[language]}` Unclear how dollar signs are involved.

Comment: Array and Object in JavaScript both have keys that can be accessed the same way. Array have number keys like 0 1 2 etc and Object has keys you defined. So you can access them just like in an array `object[key]`. So in your case `item[language]`

Comment: @DaveNewton, I thought I could achieve it using a similar logic as when passing a variable into a string! (`$ ... `) Obviously wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to map over an array and render properties from each object in a div.

Have you tried using bracket notation instead of dot notation? This is really handy when the property name is stored in a variable.

For example, `item[language]` will get the property from the `item` object based on the value in the `language` variable.

So if you write `<p>{item[language]}</p>`, it should give you the result you're looking for. This expression will evaluate the `language` variable and use its value to fetch the correct property from the `item` object.

So you could update your map function like so:

```
{array?.map((item) => (
  <div key={item.ID}>
    <p>{item[language]}</p>
  </div>
))}
```

This will render the text in the language specified in your language variable for each item.

Comment: I can't believe it is so easy, thank you Emre & @Lith. I had no idea this also works with objects, it cost me hours of my life ;)